# Can i use long double to compute integers in c language

Tags: c, factorial, long-double

I try to write a factorial function to compute a large number(factorial(105)),its result have 168 digit, so use long double, but it seems to be a error, can't it use like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

long double factorial(long double n,long double base = 1){
  if (n <= 1){
    return 1*base;
  }else{
    return factorial(n-1,n * base);
  }
}  
int main(){  
    printf("%.0Lf\n",factorial(25));     // this result is correct

    printf("%.0Lf\n",factorial(26));    
    //correct result is 403291461126605635584000000,but it return 403291461126605635592388608
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: <s>Nope. [`ceil(log2(108!)) = 559 bits`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log2(105!)).</s> EDIT: Nevermind, you're using a double. But IIRC, the exponent still doesn't have enough bits to represent this.

Comment: Strongly suggest using the header file: `bignum.h`  which if it is not already on your computer can be downloaded from:  [bignum.h](https://tls.mbed.org/api/bignum_8h_source.html)

Comment: @user3629249: How are you going to "use a header file"? Header files are useless without the actual library these header files belong to. There's no point in "downloading it" if it is not "on your computer". It will achieve absolutely nothing.

Comment: @AnT,  Naturally, there is a library file associated with this header file.  However, I figure the OP should know that relationship by now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Back of the envelope calculation: 25! is slightly more than 10<sup>25</sup>; three orders of magnitude is roughly 10 bits, so you would need roughly 83 bits of mantissa even just to represent precisely the result.

Given that a `long double`, on platforms that support it, is generally 80 bits *for the whole value* (not just the mantissa!), apparently there's no way you have enough mantissa to perform that calculations of that order of magnitude with integer precision.

*However*: factorial here is a bit magic, as many of the factors contain powers of two, which just add binary zeroes to the right, which do not require mantissa (they end up in the exponent). In particular:

```
25! = 2   4   2   8   2    4    2    16    2    4     2    8    = 2²² · m
        3   5 3 7   9 5 11 3 13 7 15    17 9 19 5 21 11 23 3 25
```

(m being the product of all non-2 factors, namely m = 3<sup>10</sup> · 5<sup>6</sup> · 7<sup>3</sup> · 11<sup>2</sup> · 13 · 17 · 19 · 23, so effectively the data we have to store in the mantissa)

Hence, our initial estimate exceeds the actual requirements by 22 bits.

It turns out that

log<sub>2</sub>(f) = 10·log<sub>2</sub>3 + 6·log<sub>2</sub>5 + 3·log<sub>2</sub>7 + 2·log<sub>2</sub>11 + log<sub>2</sub>13 + log<sub>2</sub>17 + log<sub>2</sub>19 + log<sub>2</sub>23 = 61.68

which is indeed just below the size of the mantissa of 80 bit long double (64 bit). But when you multiply it by 26 (so, excluding the factor 2, which ends up in the exponent, by 13), you are adding log2(13) = 3.7 bits. 61.7+3.7 is 65.4, so from 26! onwards you no longer have the precision to perform your calculation exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, nobody knows what `long double` can or cannot represent. Specific properties of the format depend on the implementation.

Secondly, X86 extended precision floating-point format has 64-bit significand with explicit leading `1`, which means that it can represent contiguous integers in ±2<sup>64</sup> range. Beyond that range representable integers are non-contiguous (i.e. they begin to "skip" with wider and wider gaps). Your factorials fall far outside that range, meaning that it is perfectly expected that they won't be represented precisely.

Comment: I would have said that, as regular binary64/binary32 formats, it uses an _implict_ leading 1... is that a typo or it is actually different?

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yes, it is actually different. It uses *explicit* 1. This is rather natural: 80 bit extended precision x86 format is exactly the format used internally by FPU registers. All actual calculations are done in this format. And it is apparently more efficient to have that leading 1 explicitly present when it comes to actual calculations. Meanwhile, 32 bit and 64 bit are more like "packed" storage formats. When they get "unpacked" into FPU registers, that leading 1 becomes explicit.

Comment: Well, TIL! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Since 105! is a *huge* number that does not fit in a single word (or two of them), you want [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), also known as **bignum**s. Use the [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) to get an idea of how big 105! is and read the wikipage on [factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).

Standard C (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) to check) don't have bignums natively, but you'll find many libraries for that.

I recommend [GMPlib](https://gmplib.org/). BTW, some of its code is hand-written assembly for performance reason (when coding bignum addition, you want to take advantage of *add with carry* machine instructions).

I recommend to avoid writing your own bignum operations. The existing libraries use very clever algorithms (and you'll need to make some PhD work to get something better). If you try coding your own bignum library, it probably will be much worse than competitors (unless you spend years of work).